# npm start some compilation error. Browser says Cannot GET /

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Created a new Angular application and this error of `module build failed` was occurring. And compiler is not permitted to make a new directory. Error is down below. Please suggest.

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit

./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):       
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\Capstone\shopForHome\Home-Products\.angular'

./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\Capstone\shopForHome\Home-Products\.angular'

./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&reconnect=10 - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\Capstone\shopForHome\Home-Products\.angular'

./src/styles.css - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\Capstone\shopForHome\Home-Products\.angular'

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - NGCC failed.



** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: do you have the right permissions? It says the compiler was unable to create a folder  in the mentioned directory. Check this line `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\Capstone\shopForHome\Home-Products\.angular'
`

Comment: I am running this in vs code. should i try with admin? its my personal pc so there is no issue of authorization

Comment: Yes, please run it as admin and try. If not, changing the folder permission would work fine as well.

Comment: Yes I have run it in admin and its working thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have the right permissions? It says the compiler was unable to create a folder in the mentioned directory. Check this line

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\Capstone\shopForHome\Home-Products\.angular'`

Please run it as admin and try. If not, changing the folder permission would work fine as well.

---

Posting it as an answer because the above answer doesn't actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have tried this in VS Code, when making a new project like npm and flutter, VS Code will ask for your authorization/permission if you trust them to author the files within that directory

Comment: Yes I have run it in admin and its working thanks for the help.